# In the cucumber console it returns the string relative to the block that goes into error but with an error inside on a different point of the code

Tags: javascript, console, protractor, cucumber

Often when there is a failure in the test, in the cucumber console it returns as failed a string relative to a "When" block that works correctly, while in the description of the error, a reference is made to an error on a different point of the code with respect to the relative string to the indicated block:

```
× When I look at the summary after the product # definitions\node_modules\cucumber\src\support_code_library_builder\define_helpers.js:90
       AssertionError: expected 'https://www.mgmysite.com/products/797-396aa93696ce' to include 'WU '
```

The string error is related to a check, the description is related to another check. Why? What can I do to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Post code, what you have so far. where it breaks.

Comment: @ASPiRE Hi, thank you for your answer. I know which is the problem related to the errors and this is a bug of the site so I don't have to fix this. But I don't understand why in console is shown as failed not the string related to the block where there is the error, but another block that never fails is shown as failed